autolinkLibrariesFromCommand: process cmd /c npx @react-native-community/cli config exited with error code: 1
I'm learning react native version 0.76. I install dependency npm install react-native-safe-area-context this install latest dependency version 5.0.0 when i install this dependency problem started with auto link library.
ERROR: autolinkLibrariesFromCommand: process cmd /c npx @react-native-community/cli config exited with error code: 1
due to this error i can't clean and build my project with command:
cd android ./gradlew clean, my react native project unable to build and not running.
I uninstall the dependency but again this error autolinklibrary I see in my project, I restart my vs code editor and my pc also but nothing is working.
Later again I install dependency with this command npm install react-native-safe-area-context@4.4.0 but problem not solved.
I'm stuck here from 7-10 days but my problem not solved help me to move forward in my react native project.
settings.gradle file
pluginManagement { includeBuild("../node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin") }
plugins { id("com.facebook.react.settings") }
extensions.configure(com.facebook.react.ReactSettingsExtension){ ex -> ex.autolinkLibrariesFromCommand() }
rootProject.name = 'blogmobileapp'
include ':app'
includeBuild('../node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin')


PS E:\react-native-project-development\react native without expo\blogmobileapp\android> npx react-native run-android
info Installing the app...
8 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 6 up-to-date

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor 

ERROR: autolinkLibrariesFromCommand: process cmd /c npx @react-native-community/cli config exited with error code: 1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'E:\react-native-project-development\react native without expo\blogmobileapp\android\settings.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'.
> begin 0, end 1024, length 51

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 7s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
ERROR: autolinkLibrariesFromCommand: process cmd /c npx @react-native-community/cli config exited with error code: 1 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * Where: Settings file 'E:\react-native-project-development\react native without expo\blogmobileapp\android\settings.gradle' line: 3 * What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'. > begin 0, end 1024, length 51 * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 7s.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

this is my node.js output
info Opening app on Android...
info Opening app on Android...
info A dev server is already running for this project on port 8081.
info A dev server is already running for this project on port 8081.
info Installing the app...
info Installing the app...
Timed out waiting for finished message from client socket connection from /127.0.0.1:49826 to /127.0.0.1:50151. Discarding connection.
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 4 busy and 1 incompatible and 3 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
> Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
> Task :gradle-plugin:shared:checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
> Task :gradle-plugin:shared:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:shared:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :gradle-plugin:shared:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :gradle-plugin:shared:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:shared:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:pluginDescriptors UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:jar UP-TO-DATE
8 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 6 up-to-date

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor

ERROR: autolinkLibrariesFromCommand: process cmd /c npx @react-native-community/cli config exited with error code: 1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'E:\react-native-project-development\react native without expo\blogmobileapp\android\settings.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'.
> begin 0, end 1024, length 116

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.


You'll want to [edit] to add the settings.gradle file to the question text to ensure that there's enough information given to allow an answer.

@Charles Duffy hello sir, I add my settings.gradle file to my question review that file and help me.

Thank you -- that confirms that your settings.gradle is pretty much stock (no changes other than project name), so problems presumably come from the autolink plugin not behaving well with one of your dependencies. Some bugs fitting that general description have been fixed by newer versions of react-native (if in fact you're not already using the latest one), but likely reproducing the issue may require digging into the dependency set; as the log message says, using --stacktrace to get log of exactly where the failure originated might be necessary.

(That said, if you make sure you're providing a [mre] with all the steps needed for others to see the problem themselves starting from scratch, that way we could collect the stack trace on our own instead of needing to ask for it to be added to the question).
